# C++. Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ public __thiscall

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть шаблон и cpp файл и вылетает такие ошибки. Кто может подсказать может я где то не подключил еще что то?
Source.cpp

```
#include "CustomClass.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Song song1("Song1", "flac", 8, "01/01/1345", "RW", "1:30"); //constr. with params
    Song song2("Song2", "mp3", 12, "01/01/1455", "W", "0:30");
    Song song3; //defolt constructor
    Song song4(song1); // copy constructor

    double doubleTemp;
    string stringTemp;

    cout << " Enter file Name: ";
    cin >> stringTemp;
    song3.setFileName(stringTemp);

    cout << " Enter file type: ";
    cin >> stringTemp;
    song3.setType(stringTemp);

    cout << " Enter file size: ";
    cin >> doubleTemp;
    song3.setSize(doubleTemp);

    cout << " Enter file date: ";
    cin >> stringTemp;
    song3.setDate(stringTemp);

    cout << " Enter file attribute: ";
    cin >> stringTemp;
    song3.setAttribute(stringTemp);

    cout << " Enter file duration: ";
    cin >> stringTemp;
    song3.setDuration(stringTemp);

    tab();
    print(song1);
    print(song2);
    print(song3);
    print(song4);

    return 0; //destructo call
}
```

**CustomClass.h**

```
#define UNTITLED_CUSTOMCLASS_H
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Song {
private:

    string fileName;
    string type;
    double size;
    string date;
    string attribute;
    string duration;

public:
    Song();
    Song(string fileName, string type, double size, string date, string attribute, string duration);
    Song(const Song& obj);
    ~Song();

    string getFileName();
    void setFileName(string);

    string getType();
    void setType(string);

    double getSize();
    void setSize(double);

    string getDate();
    void setDate(string);

    string getAttribute();
    void setAttribute(string);

    string getDuration();
    void setDuration(string);

    void checkFileName(string& fileName);
    void checkType(string& type);
    void checkSize(double& size);
    void checkDate(string& date);
    void checkAttribute(string& attribute);
    void checkDuration(string& duration);
};

void print(Song& obj);
void tab();

#endif //UNTITLED_CUSTOMCLASS_H
```

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: Я предполагаю, что ошибка связана с тем, что вы еще не написали реализации для функций и конструкторов. Или в файле с реализацией забыли подключить `#include "CustomClass.h"`. Так же в файле `CustomClass.h` не хватает самой первой строчки `#ifndef UNTITLED_CUSTOMCLASS_H`

Comment: Да понял, спасибо